# C++ Time measurement of functions

Tags: c++, gprof, time-measurement

I need to measure the time of a C++ programs, especially the overall running time of some recursive functions. There are a lot of function calls inside other functions. My first thought was to implement some time measurements functions in the actual code.

The problem with gprof is, that it prints out the time of class operators of a datatype, but i only need the infomartion about the functions and "-f func_name prog_name" wont work.

So, what is the most common way in science to measure time of a numerical program?

Its something like this:

```
function2()
{
}
function1()
{
  function2();
  funtcion1();
}
int main(){
function1();
}
```

Comment: The code you have here is an infinite recursion. I'll give you an answer if you can define what you mean by "overall running time of some recursive functions". For example: do you mean the time that would be saved if function F could be made infinitely fast? [*Don't expect gprof to give you a sensible answer for recursive functions.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771)

Comment: time taken to execute a complete function http://stackoverflow.com/a/40380118/6180077

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the GNU package, i.e. gcc, you can try gprof. Just compile your program with -g and -pg flags and then run
`gprof <your_program_name>`

gprof: http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html

EDIT:
In order to increase the level of detail you can run gprof with other flags:

-l (--line) enables line by line profiling, giving you a histogram hits to be charged to individual lines of code, instead of functions.

-a Don’t include private functions in the output.

-e `<function>` Exclude output for a function `<function>`. Use this when there are functions that won’t be changed. For example, some sites have source code that’s been approved by a regulatory agency, and no matter how inefficient, the code will remain unchanged.

-E `<function>` Also exclude the time spent in the function from the percentage tables.

-f `<function>` The opposite of -e: only track time in `<function>`.

-F `<function>` Only use the time in `<function>` when calculating percentages.

-b Don’t print the explanatory text. If you’re more experienced, you can appreciate this option.

-s Accumulate samples. By running the program several times, it’s possible to get a
    better picture of where time is spent. For example, a slow routine may not be called
   for all input values, and therefore you maybe mislead reading where to find
  performance problems.

Comment: tried that as mentioned...im not getting any information about the functions i need...only of some class operators of a datatype

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please try now, and let me know how did it go.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What doesn't work? What's the error?

Comment: Ah, i thought the flag -f will only print me the output for this function...it works but shows me every function.

Comment: No, i dont....on a similar program it shows me only three functions and neither flag would change that.

Comment: maybe the -l flag will be more helpful to you?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the class's function, e.g. `gprof -f 'foo::foo(std::string, int)' a.out`

Comment: No, thank you...i just used clock() now....dont really need the time measurement to be to exactly

Answer (score 1):

If you need higher precision (for functions which do not take more than few (or less) milliseconds), you can use [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now):

```
auto beginT = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
//Your computation here
auto endT = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endT - beginT).count()
```

The `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` can be found in `chrono` header and is part of C++11 stadard.

Comment: Thx, but actually I dont need higher precision

Comment: @Biler It works perfectly for low precision as well and it is part of STL. You can cast the result to whatever time unit you need which is very convenient.

Comment: I have to save the data in a variable and use this as a function parameter to sum up the time for the overall function calls.

Comment: @Biler If you need to do the measurement inside function then i am afraid the only solution would be to add `bool` to the parameter list which denotes whether the time shall be measured or not. The function would then - when it calls itself - just pass false so the time is not measured inside all the recursions. The user application would the pass on true which would cause time measurement on the first call of the function. This way you would not need to sum everything up

Comment: Thx, but please take a look of my first post. Thats the situation and i dont know how i can get the overall time measurement for every function. So that i can print in the main function the run times of function1, function2, function3

Comment: @Biler Sorry, I thought you needed time just for all of the recursive functions together. In this case yes, you would need to add up all the times, if you want time of just one recursion. Are you sure you cant find way to avoid recursion? Many implementations can be changed to avoid it. In your case doing so will solve your time measurement issues.

Comment: I simplified it...and used clock() for time measurement.

Comment: @Biler If you have found solution, it is good practice here on SO to post it and accept it so the thread is marked as solved (unless you want to mark the most useful answer instead).