# Proper use of memory with dynamic array lengths in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic-arrays

When creating dynamic arrays would the following code be considered "correct" in terms of memory use, and performance? Please explain why / why not.

My function getFifoData takes a pointer to a receive buffer, and internally calculates how long the message is based on the current FIFO size using getFifoThreshold.

```
int serial_spi_handler::getFifoData(unsigned char * rxBuf) {
  uint16_t currentFifoThreshold = getFifoThreshold();
  const int msgLength = (currentFifoThreshold * 2) + 1;

  std::vector < uint8_t > txBuf;
  txBuf.reserve(msgLength);

  uint8_t tBuff[txBuf.size()];
  tBuff[0] = 0xC2;

  int bytesWritten = readWrite(busDescriptor, tBuff, rxBuf, msgLength);

  if (consoleLogging) {
    printf("getFifoData function, wrote: %d bytes\n\r", bytesWritten);
  } else if (diagOutput) {
    qDebug() << "getFifoData function, wrote: " << bytesWritten << " bytes";
  }
  return msgLength;
}

//Header of readWrite:

//int readWrite(int busDescriptor, uint8_t *pTxBuffer, uint8_t *pRxBuffer, int length);
```

Comment: This is definitely not correct, for at least two reasons. Variable lengths arrays are not standard C++. Furthermore, in the shown code, `txBuf.size()` will always be 0, no matter what, and this is certainly not correct.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I thought VLA’s were part of the C99 standard, it’s just that a surprisingly high number of compilers haven’t gotten around to fully supporting a 20 year old standard.

Comment: Sure. But this is C++, not C. Actually, there's a third reason here: after `txBuf` is used for the sole purpose of determining that its `size()` is 0, it is not used at all from that point on. Something is definitely lost in translation, around here.

Comment: @van And in any case, they are optional in C99 and will hopefully eventually be completely removed.

Comment: @vandench -- VLA's are, indeed, part of C and, presumably, that mythical language C/C++, but they're not part of standard C++. <g>

Comment: excellent point @SamVarshavchik ! By changing txBuf.size() to txBuf.capacity() I should always get a non-zero value.

Comment: That would address only one of three incorrect things here, and does nothing to address the other two.

Comment: @Eric `uint8_t tBuff[txBuf.size()];` -- Why didn't you use `std::vector<uint8_t>` here?  If it is because you will need a `uint8_t*` later on in the code, then that is what `vector::data()` is for.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I didn't realize it could be used like that (but it makes sense), and I wont have 2 instances of it in memory! Does this vector go out of scope at the end of the function like a normal variable or do I have to explicitly delete it? I appreciate all the comments! Ive changed the code to: ```std::vector<uint8_t> txBuf;
    txBuf.reserve(msgLength);
    txBuf.insert(txBuf.begin(), 0xC2);

    int bytesWritten = readWrite(busDescriptor, txBuf.data(), rxBuf, msgLength);```

Comment: A `vector` cleans up the memory it allocates for itself when it goes out of scope.  So there is no need to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "correct"; your code is not correct at least in the sense mentione by @SamVarshavchik, and which a compiler will tell you about:

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int getFifoData(unsigned char*)’:
a.cpp:20:29: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘tBuff’ [-Wvla]
   uint8_t tBuff[txBuf.size()];
```

If you want to understand why C++ has no VLA's read this SO question:

[Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/1593077)

## Issues with the code

Here are some issues I believe you should consider.

#### Confusing names

- The function `readWrite()` - does it read? does it write? does it do both? Who knows.
- Don't clip names. If you want to name a buffer, call it `my_buffer`, not `my_buff`. Similarly, `diagnostic_output` not `diagOutput`.
- No impromptu initials. What's a `tBuffer`? Is it a test buffer? A **t**ransaction buffer? A **t**ransmission buffer? A **t**emporary buffer?
- Not everyone knows what RX means.
- `getFifoData()` - what does it even do? Is its parameter a "FIFO"? That's not what the parameter name says. And if it is - where is that information we supposedly get? There's no destination buffer that's passed for use, nor a container that's returned.

#### Chance of buffer overflow / invalid memory access

- Why does `getFifoData()` take a buffer without also taking its length as well?
- Better yet, why can't it take a [`span`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/1593077)?

#### Use of dynamically-allocated buffers

Both `std::vector` and the variable-length array are dynamically-allocated memory. VLAs have their own issues (see link above), but as for vectors - you would be performing a memory allocation call on each call of this function; and that might be expensive if it gets called a lot.

#### Logging

Printing to the console or to a file is slow. Well, sort of slow, anyway - this is all relative. Now, this happens within an "if" statement, but if you've configured your app to log things, you'll be paying this price on every call to `getFifoData()`.

## Time it!

Finally, - if you're worried about performance, [time your function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387586/measuring-execution-time-of-a-function-in-c), or [do it with a profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479383/c-time-measurement-of-functions). Then you can see how much time it actually takes and whether that's a problem.